# Editing favorite tags from tabs bar : list is not saved

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, new-nav

repro :
* from any tab, go to favorite filter and click edit 
[image]

- add a tag and click apply
- return to home page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tagFilter=favorite

**-> the freshly added tag is missing**

edit : also  the tags in the fav bar do not match favorite of the "side" bar 
[image]